# How to fix WordPress Website showing Unknown results in Google?

Tags: wordpress, search, meta

I was exploring my WordPress powered website and I found some unknown results in Google Search which I had never seen before and isn't related to my website.

[See the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh1ik.jpg)

I have also installed and configured the WordFence Security plugin. I also checked the Sucuri Site check tool but none of the tools showed any type of virus alerts.

The site I need help with is : [Link Deleted by User]

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Unknown results in google search results. Search for site:apkclash.com..The results is of 404 pages shown in the image.

Comment: Is this the new wordpress!

Comment: Yes, installed on the last day of November 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the Google Search Console. Some of the URL indexed by Google is a 404 URL, so manually check for the URL from Google Search Console, remove the indexed URL which are a 404 URL.

https://search.google.com/search-console/about

Comment: how to remove 404 indexed urls from google? I used url inspection tool and it showed not indexed label.

Comment: Use Google, you will find plenty of answers, I can not guide you from here, since its a process to do which can't be done in a single step.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Yoast SEO plugin
2. Add metadata with [Yoast](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/titles-and-meta-descriptions/).
3. Create a XML site map
4. Submit your site map at google console

Comment: Sorry man, it's an outdated way. Anything else you can guide on?

Comment: That's the new one, previously google had a crawl request button. Just had to push the button, & google crawled it. Now you have to wait. Submitting XML is the fastest available now. May be  any other community member may offer a better solution. (if there any ) Good Luck ;)

Comment: Moreover, if you search google for site:apkclash.com, then you will see some results with title Dogma Responsive Architectural Template. And if you open that with google cache then it will show another site's URL. See the snapshot here. https://i.imgur.com/uQ4BnP6.png

Comment: I see this http://prntscr.com/qhkp6f http://prntscr.com/qhkp23 , maybe you seeing cached version? Try incognito?

Comment: @GeetikaJain Did you started to use the Google Search Console, please follow the instruction provided there, verify your domain either by adding provided meta data or by uploading the files. And then after verifying the ownership of the domain name, you will see the pages indexed by Google. You can reindex or remove the URL for there.

Comment: @Earid Please get some more down and you will see the results. Those results are 404 pages and google is not showing them in Coverage>>404 Pages or in Coverage>>Soft (404). I also applied for Google Adsense yesterday and today it showed the error of Scraped Content. So, my another concern is if too much 404s affect Adsense?

Comment: And, the 404s showing in search results are never created by me and if you open them with Google Cache, they show a different URL of a different website as I showed above in the screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/uQ4BnP6.png  .....

Comment: For proper explanation and difference, see this screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/rIGDX7P.png

Comment: check current result not archived result. Archived thing will be there forever. Current index looks ok.

Comment: You mean what I am not able to understand. Please be more simple.

Comment: You seeing archive, not current result. Archive = previous state that saved.

Comment: Do you mean a type of cache that my browser is letting me see? But I tried to fetch the results in the Incognito mode and in the different browser also. Tell me if there is nothing to do on my side and google will do it sometime later. Then, there will be no worries.

Comment: it's archived. Current version is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Have you uploaded/submitted a valid sitemap.xml to your google search console?

Comment: Yeah, I've submitted all the sitemaps.